# Several Specific Character Set attributes in a single DICOM object

Tags: dicom

I came across DICOM objects that contain sequences in private tags; each item in that sequence contains its own Specific Character Set (0008,0005). All Specific Character Set elements have the same value.
I also found that these extra Specific Character Sets create problems in some applications.
Is it allowed by DICOM standard to have multiple Specific Character Sets in a single object? If it is, what are the scope rules?

I could not find the answer in Nema documents. I also check several DICOM Conformance Statements, with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything about sequence encoding is written in PS3.5, chapter 7.5 and in PS3.3 for each individual sequence. In neither of these documents, you will find references to including the attribute Specific Character Set.

Long story short: This is plainly wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not about multi-valued Specific Character Set. It is about several Specific Character Set attributes in sequences. 
That is: one on the top level. Then there is a private attribute VR SQ, which items contain their own Specific Character Set attribute. Not multi-valued.

Answer (score 2):

Including Specific Character Set is explicitly allowed in DICOM.  The reference is here:

[DICOM PS3.5](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part05.html#sect_7.5.3)

Specifically, the standard says:

> An encapsulated Data Set shall only include the Specific Character Set (0008,0005) data element if the Attribute Specific Character Set is defined in the IOD for that sequence of items.
>
> Note: An encapsulated Data Set does not include the Specific Character Set data element unless the Specific Character Set Attribute is defined as part of the IOD for that sequence.
>
> If an encapsulated Data Set includes the Specific Character Set Attribute, it shall apply only to the encapsulated Data Set. If the Attribute Specific Character Set is not explicitly included in an encapsulated Data Set, then the Specific Character Set value of the encapsulating Data Set applies.

In this case an "encapsulated Data Set" is a DICOM sequence. Technically since you are seeing the attributes in a private sequence, this is not legal, although this could occur when an IOD defines it (specifically for DICOMDIRs).

Comment: Thanks Steve, I think I did not make my question clear. In my case, the Specific Character Set elements are embedded in a Private Data Sequence. These are not defined in any IOD. Since the condition in the quoted text "shall only include ... if the Attribute Specific Character Set is defined in the IOD in that sequence of items" is not met in case any of Private Data Sequence, the Specific Character Set shall not be included in such data sequences.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense dmitry.  I've edited the answer to say its illegal as is actually the case.

Comment: Hm, is it true in general, that private data sequences never have an IOD or are they rather to be considered as adhering to an "unknown IOD" that only the respective vendor knows? In that case, they could specify the "private IOD" to contain a "Specific Character Set" attribute. The question is whether one has to expect and handle that in general? Technically it seems feasible.

Comment: I am not aware of anything like "Private data sequence IOD". Neither anything like that is in PS3.3 Annex A. I guess manipulations with private data are limited to Private Creator rules. The problem is, the parsing library does not know which Private Creator to ignore; also I suspect that a failure to interpret a Specific Character Set might fail further parsing.